# EXTJS 4.2 : Copy Selected Gridrows from One grid to another Grid in a new Window on button click

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have a Grid Panel which has a checkcolumn as its selection model and a few rows. I need to have a model where in on a buton click, a new window opens containing a grid wherein all the selected rows from the previous grid appear .

How do I go about achieving this? I have tried loading the rows into a new Store and passing this store to the new Grid. Also a store to store transfer of data seems infeasible?

Comment: "I have tried loading selected rows into new store and passing this store to  new grid" - whats wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to new created component. So you can use passed value for load the store.

basicly you can pass value to your custom component like this;

```
Ext.create('AppName.yourCustomComponent',{
     yourCustomField : yourCustomValue
});
```

And you can handle this passed data in your custom component like this;

```
Ext.define('AppName.yourCustomComponent', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window', //in your stuation
    initComponent : function(){
        alert(this.yourCustomField);  // your custom value here 
        this.callParent( arguments );
    }
});
```

I also tried to implement your problem at the fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1895).